# Unable to install Microsoft SQL Server through docker

Tags: sql-server, docker

% docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-linux
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for microsoft/mssql-server-linux, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:ios]? Where did you get the `pull` command? Did you just guess what it might be? It should be `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest` unless you need a very specific flavor. This change to `mcr` happened [over 3 years ago](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/opensource/2019/01/17/improved-discovery-experience-microsoft-containers-docker-hub/) so, if you got that from some blog post from before then, I recommend always looking around for newer content too.

Comment: It is critically important to the community that you do your own research before posting a question.  Doing so helps reduce the noise in stack overflow and allows difficult questions to be seen and answered more quickly. Other than that, welcome!  We're glad you're here!

Comment: I am a new Mac user and it has been little difficult for me as there are too many references in google and YouTube to learn something new. Sorry to create noise in stack overflow because of my question. the video references I am using are the latest ones but still its working fine for them . So I got confused and took it here.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&preserve-view=true&pivots=cs1-bash):

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```